# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement c#.net Winforms Devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I get date from DateEdit and try to Store into Access Database. But it show error like this

`Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.`

my insert statement is this

```
 OleDbCommand top = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO invoice(invoice_number,order_number,customername,status,subtotal,tax,total,date) VALUES (" + inno + "," + odrno + ",'" + name + "','"+ chk1 +"' ,"+ subtottal +","+ tax +","+total+",'"+date+"')", conn);
 top.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Except Date remaining values store successfully but how can i store date ??

I get date like this `DateTime date = dateEdit1.DateTime;`

Help me.

Comment: replace date with `date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: You may want to read up on [parameterised queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Comment: Hi wudzik, where i want to change exactly ?                         `string date = dateEdit1.DateTime.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")` like diz ah ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DATE` is a [`reserved keyword`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx) for Microsoft Access. You shoud use it with square brackets like `[DATE]`

And you should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
OleDbCommand top = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO invoice(invoice_number,order_number,customername,status,subtotal,tax,total,[date]) 
                                     VALUES (@invoice_number, @order_number, @customername, @status, @subtotal, @tax, @total, @date)", conn);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoice_number", inno);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order_number", odrno);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customername", name);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", chk1);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subtotal", subtotal);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tax", text);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", total);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
```

As a general recommendation, don't use reserved keywords for your identifiers and object names in your database.